# Walmart Email Verify Not Being Received

Tags: walmart-api

I have applied for the Walmart developer program and tried using both Gmail and Yahoo yet have not received the email verify in either account or spam etc. I have been waiting for weeks and it tells me the email has been resent tho I never get any of them. It also saves my information yet doesn't let me log in to move forward and get my key.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar issue. But however I noticed that they have mentioned that Walmart API is in beta phase. [image]So currently new users cannot be registered, but it will be available from Jan 31st